# Vertical align middle

Tags: html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста, не могу установить вертикальную отцентровку иконки:

```css
#not_all {
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  margin-top: 25px;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .01), 0 15px 32px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .06);
  display: block;
}

#ic {
  color: #1e9ff2;
  font-size: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div id="not_all">
  <div class="vis" style="width:100%;">
    <div style="width:10%; display: inline-block">
      <i class="fas fa-signature" id="ic"></i>
    </div>
    <div style="width:88%; display: inline-block">
      <span style="display: block; font-weight: bold; font-size: 15px;">Изменено название "Новое название"</span>
      <span style="display: block; color: #75787d;">Процесс: №265</span>
      <span style="display: block; color: #75787d;">Изменил: Тест</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам следует указать `vertical-align: middle;` для родителя, то есть для `div`.

```css
#not_all {
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  margin-top: 25px;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .01), 0 15px 32px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .06);
  display: block;
}

.icon_parent {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#ic {
  color: #1e9ff2;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div id="not_all">
  <div class="vis" style="width:100%;">
    <div style="width:10%; display: inline-block">
      <i class="fas fa-signature" id="ic"></i>
    </div>
    <div style="width:88%; display: inline-block" class="icon_parent">
      <span style="display: block; font-weight: bold; font-size: 15px;">Изменено название "Новое название"</span>
      <span style="display: block; color: #75787d;">Процесс: №265</span>
      <span style="display: block; color: #75787d;">Изменил: Тест</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Будет правильней использовать flex для центрирования. Избегайте стилей в разметке. Посмотрите на сколько меньше кода стало

```css
#not_all {
  width: 500px;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  margin-top: 25px;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .01), 0 15px 32px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .06);
  display: block;
}

#not_all i {
  color: #1e9ff2;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#not_all p {
  color: #75787d;
  margin-bottom: 0 
}

#not_all p:first-child {
  font-weight: bold; 
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <div id="not_all" class="d-flex align-items-center">
    <i class="fas fa-signature"></i>
    <div>
      <p>Изменено название "Новое название"</p>
      <p>Процесс: №265</p>
      <p>Изменил: Тест</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```